# Ensure orientation of jointjs connection

Tags: javascript, graph, jointjs

I want my user to create directed graphs, quite similar to the [logic demo](http://www.jointjs.com/demos/logic) of the JointJS library I am using. There, connections are always oriented from source to targets, but this is done using a rather limiting UI: The user has to actually drag the links from a source and to a target.

I want my users to be able to freely chose where they start dragging from, and if they start dragging from a target (i.e. an input port), the end of the connection would be connected to that, and they’d be moving the beginning of the connection with the mouse.

How would I do that?